# Pandas column sometimes has one value sometimes list. Extract first element

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas column that looks like this:

```
0                      info@bakkersfinedrycleaning.com
1                             service@mobileagency.com
2                                                  NaN
3                                                  NaN
4                                                  NaN
5                                                  NaN
6    sales@sourcefurniture.com, support@sourcefurni...
7                                                  NaN
8                                                  NaN
9                           service@allfloridapool.com
```

I am trying to extract the email if there is only one and the first email if of the list if there is more than one. I can't get it to work:

Here is what I have so far and I don't know why it is giving this error:
`ValueError: Columns must be same length as key`

```
df1['Alternate_Email_1_Explorium__c'] = df1['Contact email address'].fillna('~')
df1['Alternate_Email_1_Explorium__c'] = df1['Alternate_Email_1_Explorium__c'].str.extract(r'(.+)|^(.+?),')
```

Any help would be appreciated on what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Try just `df1['Contact email address'].str.extract(r'(\S+@\S+)\b')`

Comment: Is the data in the column presented as an actual list like this example or is it a string with a comma in the middle? d = ['info@bakkersfinedrycleaning.com', np.nan, ['sales@sourcefurniture.com', 'support@sourcefurniture.com']]
pd.DataFrame(d)

Comment: @ArchAngelPwn is is presented just as a string separated by commas I believe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code should give you find the first email address from your column as long as the e-mails are separated consistently with a ','

```
df.fillna('~', inplace = True)
df['first_email_list'] = df[0].apply(lambda x : x.split(',')[0])
```

You would need to simply replace the df[0] with the name of the column that houses the email address you are currently working with and create a new column called 'first_email_list', but you could change that to whatever you would need